# How to access external DNS on iOS when it is blocked

Tags: ipad, network, dns

I need to access critical external website from an iPad which is blocked in our local network for unknown reason I yet to find out (not a porn, seriously!).

IP of that resource is still accessible but DHCP assigned DNS doesn't return proper IP. It is fairly trivial on a computer where you can edit HOSTS file. As this is not possible on iPad I tried to replace DNS with public Google DNS. To my surprise outgoing DNS requests are also blocked.

Is there any way to "emulate" HOSTS file functionality on iPad where IP is resolved locally without outgoing DNS request? Perhaps some browsers can do that?

P.S. Using proxy or running local DNS is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this is probably to use an app such as "Weblock - AdBlock for iOS" that works through proxying content. In the app you create a redirect rule for your external web site URL and to the correct IP address of the website (port number 80 for http or 443 for https).

Another possibility is using a VPN app to allow you to punch through and access other DNS servers.